# Does Ubuntu 20.04 version runs smoothly on asus laptops eg: asus tuff gaming laptop

Tags: asus

If yes, then could please list some of best laptops,
Am confused because,in Ubuntu certified laptops asus laptops are not there.
I want to buy a new laptop am confused that whether asus laptops support Ubuntu 20.04